Android system dialog uses wrong colors
I have enountered the following issue: when the biometric system dialog is shown on an Android device, it does not use light mode colors. The actual system theme (dark/ light mode) does not impact this.

The theme of the app is set in app.dart:
MaterialApp(
   theme: 
      ThemeData(
         useMaterial3: true,
      ),
),

ThemeData implements Brightness.light by default.
Explicitly using a default light theme does not work either:
theme: ThemeData.light(useMaterial3: true),

Has anyone encountered this issue?

I'm not sure if you can even change that. Seems more like a device issue, but I could be wrong

There are other apps that implement this feature and do not have the same issue. I cannot tell what causes this issue.
